# android screenrecord is not working for presentation displays

Tags: android, android-screen, android-mediaprojection

I tried `screencap` utility to take screen shot of hdmi display, it is working fine as expected. The command is `screencap -d 1 /sdcard/print.png`

The screenrecord utility is not working for non-default displays.

I tried editing and recompiling the source of screenrecord, changed display id to [eDisplayIdHdmi](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/av/cmds/screenrecord/screenrecord.cpp#541) , still it records only main display content.

Can anyone explain/point to docs, how the mediaprojection and virtualDisplay are used to duplicate main display layers/contents ?

Comment: That seems like the right change -- should have told SurfaceFlinger to use the "external" layer stack rather than "internal". I assume you're not simply mirroring the main display on HDMI? Rudimentary docs: https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#virtual-displays